# db2 - Bulk rows update with select on different tables

Tags: db2, sql-scripts

I wanted to update a column for multiple rows based on the below condition -
I want to update column AUUSRTX  of file abhipsha/AUDUSERF  only for those rows

```
WHERE AUDUSERF.AUUSRTP <> 'USR' and AUDUSERF.AUUSRTP <> 'usr'
```

and the value that needs to be updated have to come from usrprffil.uptext from usrprffil of the matching user id . User ids of both tables are as follows

```
usrprffil.upuprf = auduserf.auusrid
```

Can someone please help with a correct query for this requirement.

I wrote the below 3 queries but i am getting error as -"Result of SELECT more than one row" for 1st and 2nd query
query 1 -

```
update  abhipsha/auduserf
set AUUSRTX = (                
    SELECT usrprffil.uptext
    from usrprffil  inner join             
         abhipsha/auduserf                                            
    on upuprf =auusrid  WHERE AUDUSERF.AUUSRTP <> 'USR'            
    and auduserf.auusrtp <> 'usr'   and auusrid = usrprffil.upuprf)
```

query 2 -

```
update abhipsha/auduserf set AUUSRTX =                             
   (SELECT uptext fROM usrprffil inner                               
     join abhipsha/auduserf 
    on usrprffil.UPUPRF = auduserf.AUUSRID 
     WHERE
       usrprffil.UPUPRF in (
          SELECT AUUSRID FROM abhipsha/auduserf
          WHERE   
          AUUSRTP <> 'USR' and AUUSRTP <> 'usr'
       ) 
   )
```

for the 3rd query i am getting - null value error
query 3 -

```
update abhipsha/auduserf 
set  auduserf.AUUSRTX = (
    select UPTEXT      
    from usrprffil   
    WHERE usrprffil.UPUPRF = auduserf.AUUSRID 
    and   usrprffil.UPUPRF    in                                               
       (SELECT AUUSRID FROM abhipsha/auduserf                               
        WHERE AUUSRTP <> 'USR' and   AUUSRTP <> 'usr') 
    and uptext <> ' ' and 
    uptext is not null )
```

Null values not allowed in column or variable AUUSRTX.

Comment: You are saying "file". What Db2 platform and version?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update  abhipsha/auduserf a
set AUUSRTX =
COALESCE
(
  (                
    SELECT min(u.uptext)
    from usrprffil u
    WHERE a.auusrid = u.upuprf
  )
, AUUSRTX
)  
WHERE a.AUUSRTP NOT IN ('USR', 'usr')
```

Notes:

1. The `min` function is used to not return multiple rows from the sub-select.
2. If the sub-select returns no rows, the `AUUSRTX` column value remains as is.

You may adjust the logic above according to your needs, of course.